# MAMP - Importing Drupal database - [#2006 - MySQL server has gone away]

Tags: mysql, macos, drupal-7, mamp

OS10.10 - MAMP 3.0.7.2 - phpMyAdmin 4.2.10 - Drupal 7

Every time I try to import a SQL database while in phpMyAdmin I get an error

```
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

Tried even exporting a fresh Drupal database from phpMyAdmin and then importing it into a blank database but I receive the same error.

I Googled around a bit and found it was a [good idea](http://www.dadderley-interactive.com/mamp) to up my `max_allowed_packet to 16M`. Did so but still nothing.

**2 Questions:**

1)
How can I even check if this new `my.cnf` is being loaded in my MAMP? (anything in Terminal that I can use? Like how you can use `php --ini` for finding the loaded php file. )

2)
Is this indeed an issue with the `max_allowed_packet` or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. Did a `sudo find / -name "my.cnf"` in terminal and found one located `/Applications/MAMP_2014-10-24_15-43-56/conf/my.cnf`. Removed this, and now I can import my databases just fine.

So #2 is answered.

If anyone knows an answer for #1 that would be great. Seems MAMP is good as reading the `my.cnf` placed inside `/Applications/MAMP/Library/` as long as there are no other located else where in MAMP. But it would be neat if there was a quick way to 100% find out what .cnf file is being loaded.

Comment: Thx for the help. Check out this blog post that worked for me (add my.conf to /Applications/MAMP/conf/): http://murfitt.net/blog/mamp-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away-while-importing-database